# Syntax Error in etc/sudoers and can't edit it in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, sudo, visudo

I was/am trying to run terminal commands without having to use sudo first and must have broke the file. Now I'm trying to fix it and it's giving me this error when I try to edit with the same `sudo visudo` command.

> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 62 <<<
> sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 62
> sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
> sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

I'm on a Mac using Terminal

Is there a way to edit this file and remove what I added or reset it without harming or removing other files?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about programming, not general computer usage/troubleshooting. [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) would be a much better place to ask. However, here's a quick recommendation: the web download version of [BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/index.html) can edit system and/or invisible files (even in free demo mode).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you, posted to Different and downloading BBEdit now. Do you know how I would locate that file?